# Como poner este codigo en una funcion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

Debo hacer un programa que cambie de bases para esto cree dos codigos para pasar de base 10 a base n y de base n a base 10 pero a la hora de volverlas funciones me sale error por ejemplo con el codigo que comparto abajo intente poner "def cambiobase(numero,base):" antes del codigo pero cuando intento llamarla por ejemplo con los valores 53 y 2 me envia este mensaje de error
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 35, in <module> cambiobase(53,2) File "main.py", line 4, in cambiobase numero= int(input()) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

```
    numero=int(input())
    base= int(input())
    matriz_residuos= []
    matriz_strings=[]
    resultado= numero
    while (resultado>base):
        residuo=(resultado%base)
        matriz_residuos.append(residuo)
        resultado=(resultado//base)
    matriz_residuos.append(resultado)
    for i in matriz_residuos:
        a=str(i)
        matriz_strings.append(a)
    for n, i in enumerate( matriz_strings):
        if i=="10":
            matriz_strings[n]="A"   
        if i=="11":
            matriz_strings[n]="B"   
        if i=="12":
            matriz_strings[n]="C"           
        if i=="13":
            matriz_strings[n]="D"
        if i=="14":
            matriz_strings[n]="E"
        if i=="15":
            matriz_strings[n]="F"
    nueva_matriz=reversed(matriz_strings)
    s=""
    for i in nueva_matriz:
        s+=i
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que debes hacer si vas a usar una función y pasar el número y base como parámetros es eliminar ambos inputs.

Por otro lado:

- No debes usar `if` encadenados cuando son mutuamente excluyentes, usa `if-elif`.
- Te puedes ahorrar casi todos los ciclos, con un único `while` y una lista te bastaría en principio.
- Te aconsejo que para la salida no uses un ciclo y concatenado de cadenas, es tremendamente ineficiente dado que son inmutables. Cada concatenación implica un nuevo objeto en memoria y que el GC tenga que eliminar la última. Usa `str.join`.
- En vez de calcular el módulo y la división entera por separado, puedes hacer uso de `divmod`.

---

```
def cambiobase(numero, base):
    matriz_strings = []
    
    while numero:
        numero, residuo = divmod(numero, base)
        if residuo == 10:
            matriz_strings.append("A")   
        elif residuo == 11:
            matriz_strings.append("B")   
        elif residuo == 12:
            matriz_strings.append("C")           
        elif residuo == 13:
            matriz_strings.append("D")
        elif residuo == 14:
            matriz_strings.append("E")
        elif residuo == 15:
            matriz_strings.append("F")
        else:
            matriz_strings.append(str(residuo))

    return "".join(reversed(matriz_strings))
```

> ```
> >>> cambiobase(53, 2)
> 110101
> >>> cambiobase(53, 16)
> 35
> ```